# Orika - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/CannotCompileException

Tags: java, orika

I'm doing the following and get as reward:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    javassist/CannotCompileException
```

Does anyone know why?

```
package javaapplication1;

import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapperFactory factory = new DefaultMapperFactory();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add this package's(ma.glasnost.orika) jar file to your project build path ?

Comment: Yes. I built it from the actual snapshot. I'm using netbeans and added the jar as library.

Comment: which jar file are you using ?

Comment: It's compiled from the maven project in the target folder from the orika-core project and from there added as library in Netbeans

Comment: i guess one of the dependcy is missed. One of them is using javassist/CannotCompileException but javassist dependcy havent added to repository. Check your pom.xml, just suggestion.

Comment: You have to add Orika's dependencies to your classpath: javassist and slf4j,
better you can just create a maven project and add a dependency to Orika :)

Answer (score 0):

Orika depends on Javassist, Paranamer and SLF4J,

Please checkout this example of Spring-Orika integration

http://orika.googlecode.com/svn/branches/examples